# Wordpress: Making a menu link behave the same as a "more" button

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have a question about a wordpress menu on my site.
If you open my site in a mobile resolution (just scale it down) you can see the menu changes to a mobile version, which is nice.

I want the Sneakers + and Shop reviews + links to behave the same as the arrow button next to it, so, when mobile users click the Sneakers +, the corresponding menu will fold, just like when you tap the arrow button.

I tried checking the code but the arrow button just consists of this:

```
<i class="next-level"></i>
```

The site is www.nieuwesneakers.nl

What is the proper code or href="" to use on the  menu item?
The href right now is "#" because it's only use is to indicate next level menu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've looked at your website and am not entirely sure what exactly you are asking. I observe the behaviour on the mobile site (the available arrows and the corresponding behaviour). Where do you want this behaviour to be available to you? Also, are you familiar with Mozilla's Inspector Tool and Chrome Development Tools? If you hit `CNTRL` + `SHIFT` + `i` in Chrome while on your site, you can do a number of really cool things. The problem with Wordpress, though, is that a lot of the plugins are proprietary and the developers appear to have purposefully mal-structured their code.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment! when you click the arrow, the menu opens further. I want this to also happen when you click the corresponding  menu label (eg. Sneakers+ or Shop reviews+).

Also i tried the "inspect element" mode chrome, and unfortunately did not become much wiser.

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked at your website and am not entirely sure what exactly you
>   are asking. I observe the behaviour on the mobile site (the available
>   arrows and the corresponding behaviour). Where do you want this
>   behaviour to be available to you? Also, are you familiar with
>   Mozilla's Inspector Tool and Chrome Development Tools? If you hit
>   `CNTRL` + `SHIFT` + `i` in Chrome while on your site, you can do a
>   number of really cool things. The problem with Wordpress, though, is
>   that a lot of the plugins are proprietary and the developers appear to
>   have purposefully mal-structured their code.

Just quoting myself, above, so I can expand on it in an answer; though, as you will see, this is not really an answer to your question.

Wordpress is what is called a Content Management System (CMS; or CMA - the "A" for assistant"). It is meant to make the web available to those who do not have the background in coding necessary to publish a website of the same quality and is a part of the Web 2.0 philosophy of the internet - making the internet accessible to the world. It is a fantastic and powerful tool that has made lots of developers lots of money for far less work; however, it often means that as people encounter the CMA, they are unsure of exactly what they are doing (this context is not to imply that you are a part of that group).

As a part of that dynamic, lot's of cool things are available, like menu sliders and JQuery-based UIs, etc. All of which can get rather complicated rather quickly as the website is populated with a bunch of "cool stuff". The trouble is that - while we have access to the code for these UI plugins - the code for these plugins is written by people who know what they are doing (in both good and bad ways). The "good is that they want to offer you the best for your website (and be known as offering the "coolest stuff" around); however, as web development tools will show you, all - or, a lot - of that code is available to you.

### Motivations

So, how do the plugin developer's respond? The mal-form their code. An example pulled straight from your website:

**DO NOT EDIT** the below code (I know it is poorly formatted, that is the point!)

```
function simple_tooltip(t,e){jQuery(t).each(function(t){jQuery("body").append("<div class='"+e+"' id='"+e+t+"'>"+jQuery(this).find("span.tooltip-c").html()+"</div>");var i=jQuery("#"+e+t);jQuery(this).removeAttr("title").mouseover(function(){i.css({opacity:1,display:"none"}).fadeIn(400)}).mousemove(function(t){var e,n,o=jQuery(window).scrollTop(),a=jQuery(window).width(),s=15;e=a-2*s>=i.width()+t.pageX?t.pageX+s:a-i.width()-s,n=o+2*s>=t.pageY-i.height()?o+s:t.pageY-i.height()-2.2*s,i.css({left:e,top:n})}).mouseout(function(){i.css({left:"-9999px"})})})}jQuery(document).ready(function(t){if(dtGlobals.isWindowsPhone&&t("body").addClass("ie-mobile"),!t("html").hasClass("old-ie")){dtGlobals.isPhone=!1,dtGlobals.isTablet=!1,dtGlobals.isDesktop=!1;var e=window.getComputedStyle(document.body,":after").getPropertyValue("content");-1!=e.indexOf("phone")&&dtGlobals.isMobile?dtGlobals.isPhone=!0:-1!=e.indexOf("tablet")&&dtGlobals.isMobile?dtGlobals.isTablet=!0:dtGlobals.isDesktop=!0}window.retinizer=function(){if(t("body").hasClass("srcset-enabled")){var e=t("img:not(.retinized)").filter("[srcset]"),i=window.devicePixelRatio?window.devicePixelRatio:1;if(e.each(function(){var e=t(this),n=e.attr("srcset").split(","),o=[],a="";n.forEach(function(e){var i=t.trim(e).split(" ");o[i[1]]=i[0]}),a=i>=1.5?"undefined"!=typeof o["2x"]?o["2x"]:o["1x"]:"undefined"!=typeof o["1x"]?o["1x"]:o["2x"],e.attr("src",a).addClass("retinized")}),"undefined"!=typeof dtGlobals.logoURL){var n=dtGlobals.logoURL.split(","),o=[];n.forEach(function(e){var i=t.trim(e).split(" ");o[i[1]]=i[0]}),dtGlobals.logoURL=i>=1.5?"undefined"!=typeof o["2x"]?o["2x"]:o["1x"]:"undefined"!=typeof o["1x"]?o["1x"]:o["2x"]}}},retinizer();var i;if(dtGlobals.isMobile&&!dtGlobals.isWindowsPhone?t(window).bind("orientationchange",function(){clearTimeout(i),i=setTimeout(function(){t(window).trigger("debouncedresize")},200)}):t(window).on("resize",function(){clearTimeout(i),i=setTimeout(function(){t(window).trigger("debouncedresize")},200)}),!t("html").hasClass("old-ie")){var n=['<g id="social-500px"><path d="M11.969 13.544c1.137 1.3 2.5 2.5 4.3 2.467c2.364 0 3.775-1.795 3.775-4.08 c0-2.279-1.438-3.973-3.756-3.973c-1.848 0-3.059 1.202-4.232 2.621c-1.201-1.44-2.393-2.621-4.279-2.621 C5.477 8 4 9.7 4 12.005c0 2.3 1.6 4 3.8 4.037c1.93-0.08 2.977-1.325 4.117-2.498H11.969z M5.715 12 c0-1.011 0.656-2.114 1.865-2.114c1.233 0 2.5 1.3 3.4 2.137c-0.82 0.957-2.015 1.99-3.265 2 c-1.285-0.021-1.974-0.842-1.974-2.013H5.715z M13.146 12.099c0.867-0.94 1.941-2.123 3.219-2.123c1.246 0 2 0.9 2 2.1 c0 1.104-0.645 2.025-1.876 1.973c-1.333 0.049-2.469-0.879-3.282-1.898L13.146 12.099z"/></g>','<g id="vk"><path d="M12.235 16.191c0.372 0 0.524-0.248 0.516-0.56c-0.017-1.17 0.438-1.797 1.258-0.978 c0.908 0.9 1.1 1.5 2.1 1.502c0.418 0 1.5 0 1.9 0c1.528 0 0.166-1.54-0.916-2.54c-1.024-0.952-1.071-0.979-0.189-2.123 c1.102-1.425 2.535-3.26 1.266-3.26c-0.246 0-0.072 0-2.428 0c-0.471 0-0.501 0.277-0.672 0.7 c-0.604 1.429-1.758 3.28-2.195 3.001c-0.46-0.295-0.248-1.3-0.213-3.038c0.014-0.459 0.01-0.774-0.694-0.94 c-1.92-0.447-3.578 0.431-2.9 0.537c0.954 0.2 0.9 2 0.6 2.98c-0.387 1.558-1.851-1.235-2.457-2.623 C7.25 8.5 7.2 8.3 6.7 8.277c-0.29 0-1.558 0-1.986 0c-0.382 0-0.569 0.177-0.434 0.531c0.133 0.3 1.7 3.8 3.4 5.8 c1.718 1.7 3.4 1.6 4.6 1.597H12.235L12.235 16.191z"/></g>','<g id="tripedvisor"><path fill="none" d="M15.825 9.215c-1.584 0-2.873 1.291-2.873 2.874c0 1.6 1.3 2.9 2.9 2.876s2.873-1.292 2.873-2.876 C18.698 10.5 17.4 9.2 15.8 9.215z M15.879 13.729c-0.423 0-0.82-0.164-1.118-0.464c-0.299-0.301-0.465-0.697-0.465-1.121 c0-0.421 0.166-0.818 0.465-1.119c0.298-0.298 0.695-0.461 1.118-0.461c0.873 0 1.6 0.7 1.6 1.6 C17.464 13 16.8 13.7 15.9 13.729z"/><path
```

It's near unreadable and that is intentional. And that is a **small** portion of the code that is **all one line**. It makes replicating behavior you see difficult to isolate and - more importantly - reproduce unless you really know what you are doing.

### Non-Malintented Alteration of Script

More often than not, JavaScript (in this case) is put through this process - known as "minification" - for the purposes of ensuring that the code is as overhead-less as is possible. Minification, generally, removes whitespace, renames variables, etc. to "uglify the code" - to make is as performant as possible with respect to it's load time.

Comment: Thank you for the information, makes a lot of sense. Quite annoying actually, that replicating something as simple as a "more" button link is not as simple as just changing the href in this case, for example...

Well thanks again for the heads-up, normally i do not have problems editing code like this, but this really annoyed me because it seemed so simple..

Comment: @Matthias I could be wrong. But, I looked around at the code, briefly, and the above *seems* to be the case. From my understanding, the `href` link is used to point to two types of resources: internal and external. Internal resources are places within the same document that user can "bounce" to (Wikipedia does this, a lot). External, obviously, would be other documents. Typically, when looking at things like dynamic user-interfaces (with pop-ups, etc.), that's all handled with JavaScript and JQuery.